# How to open ".gho" image files created by Norton Ghost v11.5?

Tags: windows-explorer, norton-ghost

In the past I had a Ghost Explorer single-file `.exe` that could show everything that was in a `.gho` image.

Which version of Ghost Explorer can open `.gho` image files that were created by Norton Ghost v11.5? (For viewing,extracting etc...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The latest version, which is available on [Symantec FTP server](ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english%5Fus%5Fcanada/products/symantec_ghost_solution_suite/2.5/updates/Ghostexp-B1597.zip), will probably do.

Comment: the verion you gave is **11.0.2.1597** but there is **11.5.0.2141** 2.8 MB version around. I do not have an official link.

Comment: Alternative Link: ftp://ftp.norton.com/public/english_us_canada/products/symantec_ghost_solution_suite/2.5/updates/Ghostexp-B1597.zip

Comment: All the links are dead. I've used Symantec Ghost 11.5 on archive.org: https://archive.org/details/GhostBoot . The GUI is really old but with it I was able to extract data from a `.gho` file to a pen drive (The file was created with a backup tool from packard bell if I remember well. It was a long time ago).

Answer (score 4):

There are several Ghost Explorer versions available, such as these:

- [Ghost Explorer 2003.789](ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/products/ghost/utilities/GHO_Explorer.exe) (found [here](http://community.norton.com/t5/Other-Norton-Products/Is-Norton-Ghost-Explorer-still-available/td-p/77109))
- [Ghost Explorer 11.0.2.1597](ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/products/symantec_ghost_solution_suite/2.5/updates/Ghostexp-B1597.zip), as mentioned
- [Ghost Explorer 11.5.1.2266](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/f6ff7ce2fbd8b60199fe160491e30a56b9a60de745a944811baff6433fb29db9/analysis/) on many other sites with md5: f3b71c000240fe7a001803fd75752e93 (for sha256 see the previous link)

Probably the last one is the newest, since recent Ghost versions use another file format.